# nginx.conf rewrite not getting triggered

Tags: nginx, configuration, url-rewriting

```
http{
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite_log on;
        root /etc/nginx/html/mysite;
        location ^~ /me/ {
           rewrite ^/me/(.*)$ /etc/nginx/html/mysite/$1.html;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is not working when I make the request `http://example.com/me/all`

I want it to be served by `/etc/nginx/html/mysite/all.html`

But the request goes to `/etc/nginx/html/mysite/me/all` ignoring the rewrite and nothing about a rewrite error in the logs (just a 404 not found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the `root` of your virtual host to `/etc/nginx/html/mysite` (line 6). In your rewrite rule you again specify the whole path `/etc/nginx/html/mysite/$1.html` (line 8). What nginx does is appending the target of your rewrite rule (`/etc/nginx/html/mysite/$1.html`) to the root of your virtual host (`/etc/nginx/html/mysite`). In you example this results in searching for the file:

```
/etc/nginx/html/mysite/etc/nginx/html/mysite/all.html
```

Such file does not exist and causes the 404.
Correct the rule to make the target a relative path with respect to `root`, as:

```
http{
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite_log on;
        root /etc/nginx/html/mysite;
        location ^~ /me/ {
           rewrite ^/me/(.*)$ /$1.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that you can get more information on these errors by reading the nginx error log (by default placed at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`). In you case it would have stated something like:

> "/usr/share/nginx/html/mysite/usr/share/nginx/html/mysite/all.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /me/all HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"